# iReport: Can the Default Expression Language Be Changed?

Tags: ireport

I'm using 4.7.1 and it's set to Groovy when starting a new report. I'd like it to default to Java. We stopped shipping groovy as a dependency and it'd be cool if I didn't have to remember to change it to Java every time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using iReport 5.0. I can change this by clicking Tools > Options. In the options box, click the iReport button at the top, then the General tab. On the General tab, click the Report defaults tab. There's a drop-down box for language and you can change the default there.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in the options to default to Java. Note that you may encounter errors if you have subreports with elements set to Groovy (As in [this case](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802566/groovy-error-java-project-ireport)). Just something to check if you run into problems.